# Separate post IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 controllers/models

`routes.rb`:

```
  resources :boards do
    resources :posts do
      resources :replies
```

Currently I have a separate column for the ID `:pid` and assign each post/reply with an incriminating PID.

In `models/reply.rb`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :board
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :pid, use: :slugged
  after_create :set_pid
  def set_pid
    post_max = Post.maximum(:pid)
    reply_max = Reply.maximum(:pid)
    if post_max.to_i < reply_max.to_i
       self.update_attributes(:pid => reply_max.to_i + 1) 
    else
       self.update_attributes(:pid => post_max.to_i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

This works, but only if there is one board. How can I separate the PIDs per board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a scope:

```
post_max = self.board.posts.maximum(:pid)
```

Comment: This returns the error: `no such column: boards.post_id: SELECT "boards".* FROM "boards" WHERE "boards"."post_id" = ? LIMIT 1`

Comment: If there's a relationship defined and you don't have the right column then you have an error in your schema. In your question it says `belongs_to :board` which means that should work, but the `has_one` is probably a mistake.

Comment: @aidiah Worth opening up another question for that, one thing at a time.